# Excel composite sum-up

Tags: excel

I want to sum up, in excel, all the clicks made by an id with a criteria
that the column day is smaller then 75

for example:

```
id      date       hour     day  clicks
7508992 24/03/2015 21:55    104  323
7206854 24/02/2015 22:23    12   197
7206854 24/02/2015 22:23    10   148
7206854 24/02/2015 22:23    11   146
7206854 24/02/2015 22:23    13   135
7206854 24/02/2015 22:23    9    115
7163322 19/02/2015 22:55    75   112
7163322 16/03/2015 23:21    1    111
7163322 18/02/2015 22:51    97   109
7163322 22/03/2015 19:54    1    109
7163322 20/02/2015 21:10    45   108
```

To demonstrate the idea, I want the following information. id no. 7206854 where day < 75

Which will result somthing like this:

```
id      date       hour     day  clicks
7206854 -          -        -    1424
7163322 -          -        -    956
...
```

I need to do this proccess for each ID that in the ID section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One simple way:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(A2:A12=7206854)*(D2:D12<75)*(E2:E12))
```

[image]

**EDIT#1**

To use a *column of uniques*, here is an example:

[image]

Note the *$* in the formula......it helps to copy downwards.

Comment: i have like 60K rows. I need a way to do it automaticly

Comment: @EranMoshe  Then adjust the limits in my formula.  My formula is only a simple example.

Comment: I dont understand. I have alot of id's not only 1 or 2. more like 1000. I need to do this proccess to every ID. You have any idea how could I do that? thanks for helping!

Comment: @EranMoshe  you would need to list the 1000 unique *id*s in a single column and use that column in a column of **SUMPRODUCT()** formulas.

Comment: I see. Do you have any idea how could i get all unique ids easily?

Comment: @EranMoshe  Copy the *id* column to another column and use Excel's remove duplicates feature in the **Ribbon's Data** tab

Comment: Alrite! I've done that. now how do i do that little trick u told me with the SUMPRODUCT() ? What exactly do I need to write in there?

Comment: I've done the following f(x): =SUMPRODUCT(--(A2:A71706=Q:Q)*(K2:K71706<75)*(L2:L71706)) where Q:Q is the row of all unique id's. Its not working, probably somthing with the syntax

Comment: @EranMoshe  See my **EDIT#1**

Comment: Thanks alot! you are my brother :>